# Combining GROUP_CONCAT DISTINCT with COUNT in Yii2 Query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, yii2, distinct

I've built the following query with the Yii2 query builder:

```
public function searchFilter() {
    $query = (new Query())
        ->select([
            'GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(a.merk), ".", m.merk ORDER BY a.merk ASC)                merk',
            'GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(b.brandstof) ORDER BY b.brandstof ASC)                   brandstof',
            'GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(a.bouwjaar) ORDER BY a.bouwjaar DESC)                    bouwjaar',
            'GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(k.kleur) ORDER BY k.kleur ASC)                           kleur',
            'GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(t.transmissie) ORDER BY t.transmissie ASC)               transmissie',
        ])
        ->from('auto_new a')
        ->join('INNER JOIN', 'tbl_merken m', 'a.merk = m.merk_id')                          //Merk
        ->join('INNER JOIN', 'tbl_kleur k', 'a.kleur = k.kleur_id')                         //Kleur
        ->join('INNER JOIN', 'tbl_transmissie t', 'a.transmissie = t.transmissie_id')       //Transmissie
        ->join('INNER JOIN', 'tbl_brandstof b', 'a.brandstof = b.brandstof_id');            //Brandstof
    return $query;
}
```

This gives me the following output:

[image]

But now I want to add a count after every value in the DISTINCT. But I don't know how to do this.

**EDIT**
This is the function that executes the query

```
public function actionSearchfilter($ac) {
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    $query = Car::searchFilter()->where(['a.ac' => $ac, 'a.flag' => '1'])->all();
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: show me a sample in normal sql .. so i can evaluete you goal

Comment: could you some more code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe?

```
->select([
    'GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(a.merk), ".", m.merk ORDER BY a.merk ASC)                merk',
    'GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(b.brandstof) ORDER BY b.brandstof ASC)                   brandstof',
    'GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(a.bouwjaar) ORDER BY a.bouwjaar DESC)                    bouwjaar',
    'GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(k.kleur) ORDER BY k.kleur ASC)                           kleur',
    'GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(t.transmissie) ORDER BY t.transmissie ASC)               transmissie',
])
->from('auto_new a')
->join('INNER JOIN', 'tbl_merken m', 'a.merk = m.merk_id')                          //Merk
->join('INNER JOIN', 'tbl_kleur k', 'a.kleur = k.kleur_id')                         //Kleur
->join('INNER JOIN', 'tbl_transmissie t', 'a.transmissie = t.transmissie_id')       //Transmissie
->join('INNER JOIN', 'tbl_brandstof b', 'a.brandstof = b.brandstof_id');              //Brandstof

->count();
return $query;
```